# how to display a list into multiple columns in gsp

Tags: html, grails, gsp

In my groovy/grails app i can get my list with check boxes (and thanks for the tips).

But what I cannot seem to get is how to display the list in multiple columns.

Here is the code in my gsp:

```
<ul class="columns" column-count="3">
        <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
               <g:checkBox checked="false" name="${ 'fileName'}"/> ${fileName <br>
        </g:each>
</ul>
```

i thought that the class="ul class="columns" column-count="3" would work as straight html but I was wrong. I still get a single (long) list.

What is the proper way to make this list into multiple columns in a gsp using groovy tags or the correct html code?

Thanks!

ironmantis7x

***** Successful UPDATE!!! *****

based on the answer I accepted, here is the code I wrote:

```
<style>
    .columns2 {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2; }
    </style>

        <ul class="columns2">
            <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
                 <g:checkBox checked="false" name="${ 'fileName'}"/> ${fileName}<br>
            </g:each> 
        </ul>   
    </div>
```

Thanks gang! You always help me expand my knowledge base and be more successful in what i love to do and that's programming software!

ironmantis7x

Comment: `ul` expects `li` children, but you're making a single multiline text

Comment: thanks @Igor Artamonov.  How do I correct this? Sorry for this basic elementary question.

Comment: also, i don't think that `column-count` is standard html attribute (still possible that supported by 3rd party js). but there're a css3 with same name, maybe you're missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, `column-count` is a CSS property, not an attribute that can be applied to the `ul` tag.  You need to have `column-count` defined via `style=` or within a separate css file (the preferred way because of SoC).

```
.columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Also, you have a list of checkbox inputs within your `ul` tag.  You should have a list of `li` (list item) tags instead:

```
<ul class="columns">
    <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
       <li><g:checkBox checked="false" name="${ 'fileName' }"/> ${fileName} </li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

Comment: Apparently, `column-count` is not very well supported in older browsers (particularly IE); you may want to look at a JavaScript solution instead ( example - [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) ).

Comment: this was the best solution for the task at hand!

Answer (score 0):

HTML code in gsp produces exactly same html as you wrote, will be sent to browser as is. So `<ul class="columns" column-count="3">` will be same `<ul class="columns" column-count="3">` in your browser.

But you're missing list elements, and putting just a single multiline (split by 
) text block. You're probably want this:

```
<ul class="columns" column-count="3">
    <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
       <li><g:checkBox checked="false" name="${ 'fileName' }"/> ${fileName </li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

or most likely this (because you didn't close `}` in your code, and `${ 'fileName'}` doesn't make any sense. also you should't put values as is, it's potential security vulnerability):

```
<ul class="columns" column-count="3">
    <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
       <li><g:checkBox checked="false" name="${fileName.encodeAsHTML()}"/> ${fileName.encodeAsHTML()}</li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

Comment: most likely because `column-count` is not a standard html attribute, you probably need a custom js to process such attribute (you mentioned in your question that it work in straight html - that's not true actually)